# Chrome: First Link(s) on Some Pages Don't Work--Why?

Tags: google-chrome

My problem: Llinks work in IE 7 and Firefox, but in a number of cases on a site I'm working on updating, the first link(s) on a page don't work in the Chrome browser even though they do from the "View Source" page. I've looked for obvious code problems and can't find any. What am I missing? Something's up, but what? Thanks for your help.

http://wilmettehistory.org/newpages/family.html

Comment: Which links, specifically, aren't working for you?  What are the symptoms?  The ones I tried work fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: They're working for me too. What version of Chrome are you running? What do you mean the links work from the "view source" page?

Comment: I'm viewing the page with Chrome 3.0.195.33 on computers running XP. The "online vital records indexes" link doesn't work for me--no rollover and can't click on it. The rest of the links on the page work. Same on similar pages. On http://www.wilmettehistory.org/newpages/archives/archives.html the links start working about halfway down the page.

BUT when I do Ctrl U and view the source code, all links work.

As long as it's not an issue for most people, I won't worry about it but it sure seems strange.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I drove my blood pressure through the roof trying to figure this out and I did, so I will help answer the question. What you need to do is locate your main element that contains the links that aren't working, then put a z-index of one on that div box.

so for instance if it is the menu that isn't working put a z-index of 1 in your menu CSS like this....

```
#leftmenu {
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    left:14px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    z-index:1;
}
```

This will force all of the stuff forward and your links will work. Voila...